# Android - Delay Ad creation when activity starts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

After an Activity Starts and the layout content view is displayed, I want a 5 second delay before an ad is generated and displayed.  Its an interstatial ad that has to be rendered on the main thread.  I think that i'm missing a simple solution?

Of course, if the user clicks a button before the 5 seconds is up, the ad is never displayed and another activity starts.

Comment: See the documentation for Timer, TimerTask, and runOnUiThread.  I believe you can also do it with postDelayed

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onPostDelayed` method to cause a callback to occur after your 5 seconds delay. Additionally, keep track of whether your activity is in the paused/resumed state and only display the ad if the Activity is in the resumed state.

```
onResume()
{
    isResumed = true;

    rootView.postDelayed(5000, new Runnable()  { /* only do something if isResumed is true */ });
}

onPaused()
{
    isResumed = false;
}
```